# make an invisible field with two constraints

Tags: python, odoo

hi how can i make a field invisible by restricting two attributes? I currently have this to make it invisible when I select the put option, but I also want it to be invisible when I select another option.

attrs = "{'column_invisible': [('parent.type_movement', '=', 'sale')]}"

This framework is ODOO 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Francisco González Mejías,

This way you can check the both option,

```
attrs="{'column_invisible': ['|', (Your First Domain), (Your Second Domain)]}"
```

Where  First it check with your Apply **First Domain** if it **Satisfies** the condition then it will perform **invisibly** and if **not** **Satisfy** the **First Condition**, then it would be **check** for the **Second Condition**.

Thanks